# VB.NET Datagridview Help Autoresize Height

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

How can I make my `DataGridView1` auto-resize?

I want to auto-resize my `DataGridView1`'s Height.

I'm stuck on this:

```
Private Sub Populate()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 1
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Device Name"

    Dim row As String() = New String() {"Samsung Galaxy A8"}


    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
End Sub

Private Sub Passwords_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Populate()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding up all of the height values of your rows then set that to be the height of your DataGridView

```
DataGridView1.Height = (DataGridView1.RowCount * DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Height) + DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight
```

or if all of your rows have diffrent heights loop through them and total the heights

```
Dim TotalHeights As Integer = DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight
For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    TotalHeights += Row.Height
Next Row
DataGridView1.Height = TotalHeights
```

If you have scrollbars enabled then they will appear. What you can do is either disable them on the component 
[image: Disable scroll bars]
or do it in your code

```
DataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None
```

Comment: No luck :(
Basically I wanted to do is auto resize the height of my DataGridView1 to the rows.height or so being generated. My rows.Items is in the code in formload "Populate()"

https://prnt.sc/ko2hnl

Comment: Sorry, I guess I did not understand the question. Have you tried taking the height value of each row in the DGV and add it together then set it as the DGV height? C#. Loop through each row in the DGV then get the `TotalRowsHeight += dgv1.Rows[0].Height` then `dgv1.Height = TotalRowsHeight`

Comment: To which datagrid event should I put these codes? on cellpainting?

Comment: The most efficient way would be after you are done loading everything or you could do it after you are calling `DataGridView1.Rows.Add()`

Comment: Sorry, but I am not very familiar yet with this DGV

This is basically what I want 
https://prnt.sc/ko2urt

Comment: Add after `Populate()` in `Passwords_Load`

Comment: This works like a charm now, thank you so much. Have come across this code already, but put in cellpainting, instead in formload.